# Android ResourcesNotFoundException however image present in all drawable folders

Tags: android, android-resources

One android user had a crash on Nexus 5X device with this report:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class ImageView
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
Caused by android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class ImageView
Caused by android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class ImageView

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x7f0700b8

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Unable to find resource ID #0x7f0700b8
```

pointing to line 61 in Mainactivity: MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:61), which is this line:

```
 this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I've found out that resource ID #0x7f0700b8 points to my image logo.png, which is present in all drawable folders (drawable,hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi) so I don't understand why the drawable is not found or what is the problem.

The imageview in XML looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bgmain">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hrady_a_zamky"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:paddingRight="32dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

and Mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Locale locale = new Locale(lng);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
  this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView language = findViewById(R.id.lang);
    ImageView logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
    ImageView award = findViewById(R.id.award);

    if (lng.equals("sk")) {
        language.setImageResource(R.drawable.en);
        logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    }

    else { language.setImageResource(R.drawable.sk);
        logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logoen);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `File>Invalidate Caches / Restart` ?

Comment: The crash is on published app. Locally I don't have this issue. It is only on Nexus device for one user. Actually I can ignore this, but if I can, I rather fix it

Comment: I have seen similar problems in the past, an area to look into is if you are using Proguard and see if it is possibly obfuscating classes from the APK. I havent seen this for images personally but i have seen it with external libaries like GSON, im not saying this is your problem, but might be a route worth checking out

Comment: well, I am not using Proguard. Strange that this crash hapeened just for 1 user and Nexus device.

Comment: I just started seeing this too. Same exact issue, but have four users seeing it.

Comment: @Mike Hall did you find any solution? I renamed the logo image, and published a new version of the app, but the same crash appeared for the same user and same device again. For sure it has to do something with Nexus only and this one image only (in my case)

Comment: I am just facing the same problem. In my case, according to crashlytics, it is a Nexus 5X with Android 6.0.1. I can also ensure that the resource not found is a png drawable present for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. In my case it is a menu icon though and crashes when the toolbar menu is inflated by androidx.appcompat library.

Comment: @Charlie did you found a solution? I have the exact same scenario

Comment: @DiegoGarcia, I just replaced the PNGs for the resource to an XML vectorized image in the drawable folder. In my case that was possible because it was a common menu icon, but I guess this solution cannot be applied in all cases. After that change, I did not get any new crash when inflating this icon so far, so I hope it is solved.

Comment: @Darksymphony did you find any solution to the problem? I am facing the exact same issue.

Comment: not really, as it is still only on 1 device. I suggest the solution from @Charlie to replace a PNG image to vectorized, u just need to find which image is problematic via it's ID

Comment: Same thing here seeing it for many version of my app and only on some not all the time.  No pattern either of phone type issue or API, seems to happen on all versions but only peridodically

Comment: See same error for Nexus 5X only from time to time and I can't replace by vector image. Someone try to use -nodpi folder ?